# How to make parent ignore the event coming from child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following parent and child. Whenever I click on child, parent should not get triggered but I can't use event.stopPropagation() because there are other event listeners that are waiting for the click event.

So whenever I click on dropdown of parent1 and the click on dropdown of parent2 then dropdown of parent1 should close and dropdown of parent2 should open which works as expected because of the eventlistner. But the issue I'm facing is, event is bubbling to parent which should be ignored by parent but capture by other event listeners.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-rnxjw9?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FDropdown.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue,src%2FApp.vue%3AL7

Comment: You're probably looking for [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-d4ca6n?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FDropdown.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue,src%2FApp.vue%3AL7-L7). Side note: dropdowns are some of the most complex UI components,  once you factor in responsiveness, touch device behavior and the fact you will likely want them to overflow containers with `overflow:hidden`. Most libs depend on third-party plugins to solve these issues. You probably don't want to develop your own dropdowns from scratch.

Comment: This was helpful, I was able to resolve the issue using `event.target.closest` on parent by adding a custom class on dropdown tag. If `event.target.closest` has the dropdown class then the alert won't get triggered. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you also need to keep the `@click` handler on the parent element, one potential solution is to use the `.self` modifier:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello" @click.self="openAlert">
    <div class="hello_title">{{ title }}</div>
    <!-- Within the dropdown component is another @click handler -->
    <dropdown class="hello_dropdown" :dropdownId="id" />
  </div>
</template>
```

There is a caveat with this approach: the event will *not* trigger on clicks of *any* child. In your example (and the snippet above), clicks on the div with class `hello_title` will not trigger the `openAlert` handler.

With a simple DOM tree, this limitation might be easy to work around. Simply add separate handlers to each descendant (you can omit the `.self` assuming the dropdown component is not a child in those descendant DOM subtrees). However, that strategy might not be desirable if your component hierarchy is complicated.

---

If a more robust solution is needed, consider creating a separate "Event Bus" Javascript module that can be imported and used by multiple components. In its simplest form, it could be a wrapper around a map of strings to handler functions:

```js
const map = {};

export function addEventListener(name, fn) {
  if (!map[name]) map[name] = [];
  map[name].push(fn);
}

export function emit(name, ...args) {
  if (map[name]?.length) {
    for (const fn of map[name]) {
      fn(...args);
    }
  }
}
```

Your dropdown components can register their listeners on the event bus (rather than the document body), and they can also emit to the bus appropriate events from a handler *whose propagation is stopped* (since you no longer need to let the event bubble up to the document body). At that point, the parent div could just use the standard, unmodified `@click` syntax, because clicks on the dropdown would be ignored.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello" @click="openAlert">
    <div class="hello_title">{{ title }}</div>
    <!-- Within the dropdown component is a @click.stop handler, delegating to the event bus -->
    <dropdown class="hello_dropdown" :dropdownId="id" />
  </div>
</template>
```